# Function activates whenever images load

Tags: jquery, onload

This is related to my previous question where the HTML is located: [Grouping siblings into a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488304/grouping-siblings-into-a-div)

I found it hard to explain what I was attempting to accomplish so I drew up a quick wireframe representation:

[image: Desired Results Wireframe]

I found a different solution from grouping the content and getting the visual that is desired. The image is being held in an anchor tag so I used jQuery to find the tallest img on the page and apply that height to the containing a tag. So instead of vertical-align bottom with a fixed height set to the content I have vertical-aligned the content to the top with a Maximum Height set to the Anchor Tag and vertical-aligned the image in that tag to the bottom.

[image: Max Height TD]

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$('.Product img').each(function() {
    maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height()); })

$('.ProductThumbnail').css({"height":maxHeight});
```

The code works perfectly. However, some of the categories have several pages and when you select the "Next Page" link the eCommerce solution uses jQuery to load in the page dynamically and the code breaks.

So, my question is "How can I have the function listed above onLoad whenever images are loaded onto the page?"

[note 1:] I have already attempted to use [imagesloaded by desandro](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) and it did not work as I had hoped it would.

[note 2:] I would also like the maxHeight to be matched for each row rather than the entire page, as the TD's are kept within TR's.

[note 3:] I can not alter the html at all. I am only allowed to make addendums to the head, a custom Header, and a custom footer. **The content is uneditable.**

Answer (score 1):

in your case you should , or have to use this function

```
$('img').ready(function(){
    console.log('image is loaded');


})
```

it will see if the element is loaded and then preform the function ...

here is an example

[jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/68dq6/)

Comment: When applied I got the following error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: img is not defined"

[Edit]: Wait realized $(img) was missing the '' but, when I added it the code broke.

Comment: Can this function work without asking for the url of the image? It is an eCommerce solution so it's loading images / information from an inventory of 1000's of items. I am also not sure what you mean about the second part of your edit?

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a delegate to each `tr` (which is triggered whenever a child `img` fires the `ready` event) that recalculates that row's height:

```
$("table#tableId tr").on("ready", "img", function(){
       var maxHeight = 0;

       $(this).find('.Product img').each(function() {
           maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height()); })

       $(this).find('.ProductThumbnail').css({"height":maxHeight});
    })
});
```

ETA: 
This code uses the `live()` method to delegate the event. With this method you can bind events to elements that do not exist yet. Note that `live()` is deprecated, and `on()` should be used, but to delegate with `on()` you need a parent element that is not replaced.

```
$("table#tableId img").live("ready",  function(){
       var maxHeight = 0;
       var $row = $(this).parents("tr");
       $row.find('img').each(function() {
           maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height()); })

       $row.find('.ProductThumbnail').css({"height":maxHeight});
    })
});
```

Comment: When applied I got the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' "

Also, can this be used on class rather than ID? I am working with an eCommerce solution so it is randomly generating IDs for the various rows and it would not be time effective to go through and rewrite this code for every row.

Comment: Yes, you can use any selector. The `on()` method was introduced to jQuery in 1.7: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: hm.. the eCommerce solution has an older version but I just linked in the newest version as well as adding "<script type="text/javascript"> var newQuery = $.noConflict(true);</script>" and one for the old one so they would not conflict and the code still does not work. No errors either. :\ [Edit:] Wait.. I must not have done it properly as the old code is not working either.

Comment: After, cross checking and making sure I am linking in the proper jQuery I determined that this code is not working as intended. The console is not showing errors, however, the anchor tags are not being altered.

Comment: is eCommerce replacing the whole table, or just the images? And is `.Product img` a valid selector from inside the context of the `tr`?

Comment: The entire table gets replaced. It, more or less, replaces the entire page, except for the header and footer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23337/discussion-between-ben-and-malk)